# Change default clock app in Samsung Galaxy Note 9

Tags: default-applications, clock, samsung-galaxy-note-9

My previous phone was Nexus 5 and I changed to a Samsung Galaxy Note 9. I'm trying to customize most of the things that I used to be the same as Note 5.

What I liked from Nexus 5 it was notifications for upcoming alarm clock which is missing in Note 9.

I tried to install Google Clock and it works as on a Nexus 5. What I am not able to solve is how to set Google Clock the default app in Note 9. I have noticed that I can't uninstall or even disable the Clock app which comes with Note 9.

I want do do this because I want that Google Assistant to use Google Clock to set alarms and not the default Clock.

Answer (score 1):

Enable developer options and ADB on your phone, and get [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) for your OS. Then run:

```
adb shell
pm list packages | grep [whatever the app name is]
pm hide [name of package]
```

Alternatively `pm uninstall -k --user 0 [name of package]` to remove it completely.

More detailed explanation here: https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/

Comment: Does this ensure that new installed clock will work as expected?

Comment: @Endri can't see why not. Just open the app info for the clock app and set the 'open as default' options.

Comment: Now 'Set as default' is grayed out. I can't click it. Will it be enabled if I follow above steps?